# Complex splitting of a String using REGEX, only discarding spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, split

In Java (JDK 11), consider the following string:

```
String hello = "333+444 5qwerty5 006 -7";
```

I am trying to come up with a RegEx that will split anything that isn't a digit, whilst keeping the separators except space. So in the above example, I would like to end up with the following array:

```
["333" , "+" , "444" , "5" , "q" , "w" , "e" , "r" , "t" , "y" , "5" , "006" , "-7"]
```

Do note the leading zeroes in **006**, and **-7**. The code I am using is the following:

```
String[] splited = s.split("((?<=[^0-9]+)|(?=[^0-9]+)|(\\s+))");
```

However, I can see that my array is keeping spaces. I can't for the life of me figure my mistake. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Turns out the requirement kept getting more complicated. Eventually I had to obtain the following collection, based on the sample input from above:

```
["333+444" , "5" , "q" , "w" , "e" , "r" , "t" , "y" , "5" , "006" , "-7"]
```

So if there is no space between an integer and operators `+ - * / % ^`, then do not split them. I have issues implementing this rule along with the fact that leading zeroes and negative numbers should not be split.

Based on that, it turns out that it is much simple to work with **The fourth bird**'s sample where `matcher()` is used instead of `split()`. The RegEx syntax is simpler to understand, troubleshoot and build upon.

Perhaps I could have asked another question to cater for the additional complexity, but I do not think it is right to use StackOverflow to keep asking very similar questions because one got stuck.

Comment: You can use a mix of `\d`, `\D`, and `\\s+` to achieve this with regex, but I think a simple once-through parser (aggregating numbers until a non-digit, and then adding non-digits as individual values) would be easier to write and more performant

Comment: @Rogue Thanks. I thought of doing the once-through parse but there were caveats and the code got too clunky to deal with crazy patterns, particularly since negative values should work. Not sure how to go about combining \d with \D in this case. Can you advise?

Comment: I also tried `(?<=[\\D]+)|(?=[\\D]+)|(\\s+)` and I got the same problem where spaces are going into my array. However if I use `(?<=[a-zA-z]+)|(?=[a-zA-z]+)|(\\s)` even though it only work for letters, spaced are no longer getting into the array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried with the `split()` method and it did not work. Turns out that it is very hard to read and troubleshoot RegEx (surprise!? /s) and I noticed that the syntax used with `matcher()` can be simpler. I got it working by modifying **The four bird**'s answer. See comments under his answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using split, you could also match all the parts:

```
-?\d+|\S
```

The pattern matches:

- `-?` Optionally match a hyphen
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `|` Or
- `\S` Match a single non whitespace char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT6ZDF/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Dp0v3U).

Example

```
String regex = "-?\\d+|\\S";
String string = "333+444 5qwerty5 006 -7";

List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string);
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allMatches.toArray()));
```

Output

```
[333, +, 444, 5, q, w, e, r, t, y, 5, 006, -7]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to expand on your example to cater for further complexity. Turns out I should split `3 + 5 -7 1+1 006` as `["3+5", "-7","1+1","006"]`. I managed to get an alternative RegEx based on your example working here: regex101.com/r/aw0DnJ/1 However I must use split() as your example uses some deprecated libraries, and I cannot get it to work with split(). Not sure why! This all looks like voodoo to me.

Comment: @pmdci Which deprecated libraries? You can see generated Java code here for your last pattern https://regex101.com/r/aw0DnJ/1/codegen?language=java

Comment: You are right. I made a little typo and hell broke lose. The deprecated warning was a red herring. Turns out that your suggestion of using matcher is much simpler to read, troubleshoot and build upon. I was able to take on your example, and enhance it as the requirements got more complicated. I got it working and it PERFECT. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

This works for your example:

```
String[] split = hello.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D) *|(?<=[^\\d -])(?=[\\d-])|(?<=[\\d-])(?=[^\\d -])|(?<=[^\\d -])(?=[^\\d -])");
```

The important parts are:

- Using `[\\d-]` instead of `\d` so minus signs are treated as "digits"
- Generally using `[^\d -]` instead of `\D` to prevent empty split elements at word ends
- Splitting after digits, but only if a non-digit follows
- Adding  `*` to capture ("delete") spaces when splitting
- Splitting between non-digits

---

Test code:

```
String hello = "333+444 5qwerty5 006 -7";
String[] split = hello.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D) *|(?<=[^\\d -])(?=[\\d-])|(?<=[\\d-])(?=[^\\d -])|(?<=[^\\d -])(?=[^\\d -])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[333, +, 444, 5, q, w, e, r, t, y, 5, 006, -7]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It is working perfectly. Is there a way to expand on this RegEx as it currently stands, and add exceptions to splits? The idea is to ensure that a math expression without spaces doesn't get split (e.g. `3+4-2` becomes `["3+4-2"]`), while one with spaces would get split (e.g. `3 + 4 - 2` becomes `["3","+","4","-2"]`. The exceptions would be: `+ - / * % ^`

Comment: @pmdci That's a different question: Ask it as a new question!